# Spotting error in the sentence " India has a long way to go to reach environmental quality similar to those enjoyed in developed economies."

Tags: grammar, errors

I am required to indicate whether the sentence " India has a long way to go to reach environmental quality similar to those enjoyed in developed economies." contains any error or not.
I am of the opinion that the word "those" in the sentence should be replaced with "that" in order to make the sentence correct. According to me, the sentence can be rewritten as "India has a long way to go to reach environmental quality which is similar to the environmental quality that is enjoyed in developed economies."  But when I look up for this sentence on Google, I find the usage of "those".
Had it been " levels of environmental quality" in place of "environmental quality", the usage of "those" probably would have been correct. I want to emphasize here that I am not a native English speaker as you might have figured out. Please help me out here.

Comment: Welcome, Harveer! I think you have already spotted the error. The _Subject-Verb Agreement_ requires _that_ instead of _those_. Other than that, it would make sense to put the definite article before _environmental quality._ However, I have reservations as to the part _enjoyed in developed economies_. I don't think one enjoys _environmental quality._

Comment: @user405662 But the Google search suggests otherwise.

Comment: *to reach environmental quality* is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a little research, which is strongly encouraged here before asking a question. Try to focus on a specific question rather than asking for proofreading commentary. Otherwise you will find your questions closed. Nevertheless, you raise at least three interesting points:

You are correct about that/those. The referent is the singular noun *quality* so the correct form is unquestionably the singular form *that*.

*has a long way to go* creates the analogy between achieving quality and arriving at a destination, so is correct and expressive.

“Quality enjoyed ...” is correct from the viewpoint of

> Enjoy =  have the benefit of something:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enjoy)

So *enjoy* is used correctly, rather than other meanings that have connotations of pleasure.

In summary, your own analysis was correct.